# Invalid modelstate: how to return to view when I have dropdownlists?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a big view with more than 40 fields. Some of these fields are dropdownlists, that I populate with a list of selectlistitems.

I am using the annotations on my viewmodel, to make some of them required.

Now I want to make the `ModelState.IsValid` check, and return to the original view with errors if there is some errors.

Problem is, if I simply make a `return View(model)`, all my dropdownlists will crash the site, as they need to be populated again to load the page.

So my question is: how do i handle the return when modelstate is invalid.

**My controller:**

```
    public ActionResult CreateSelling(SellingAdViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            SellingAdvert sellingAdvert = setSellingAd(model);

            var stored_advert = sellingAdvertService.Create(sellingAdvert);



            if (User != null && User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                if (model.AcceptPartner)
                {
                    notifyPartner(stored_advert);
                }

                return RedirectToAction("Upgrade", "Ads", new { AdvertID = stored_advert.Id });
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("ActivateAnonymous", "Ads", new { AdvertID = stored_advert.Id, anonymousId = model.UserId, AdvertType = "selling" });
            }
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

**My viewmodel (I have a SellingAdViewModel that derives from this one and add more properties):**

```
public class BasicAdViewModel
{
    public int SectorId { get; set; }
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public bool IsAnonymousUser { get; set; }
    public int AdvertId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Titel:")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Titel skal udfyldes")]

    public string Headline { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Beskrivelse:")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Beskrivelsen minimum fylde 50 karakterer")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Søgeord:")]
    public string SearchWords { get; set; }


    [DisplayName("Undertitel:")]
    public string Subtitle { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Type af drift")]
    public List<SelectListItem> OperationTypes { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int SelectedOperationTypeId { get; set; }


    [Required]
    public int SelectedSectorId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<GroupedSelectListItem> Sectors { get; set; }
}
```

Setting my dropdownlists in the first place:

My model has the `List<SelectListItem>` properties, and I fill them by having a couple of helper methods:

```
  SellingAdViewModel model = new SellingAdViewModel()
            {
                BusinessEntityTypes = ModelListHelpers.GetBusinessEntityTypes(),
                FoundedYears = ModelListHelpers.GetFoundedYears(null),
                ReasonForSale = ModelListHelpers.GetReasonForSale(),
                RevenuePrediction = ModelListHelpers.GetRevenuePrediction(),
                RevenueStatus = ModelListHelpers.GetRevenueStatus(),
                OperationTypes = ModelListHelpers.GetOperationTypes(),
                Region = ModelListHelpers.GetRegions(),
                Turnover = ModelListHelpers.Turnovers(),
                OperatingIn = ModelListHelpers.OperatingIn(),
                AmountOfEmployees = ModelListHelpers.GetAmountOfEmployees()
            };
```

Comment: I usually put the drop down lists in a TempData then if my modelstate is invalid i get them from tempdata and make another model.dropdown = (type)TempData["dropdown"];

Comment: how do you populate your dropdownlists first time? do the same using `ViewBag` at appropriate place. (i.e, in action may be). I do it this way. (and in my view, `viewbag` items as selectlistitems)

Comment: I just added how I fill my viewmodel :) I do this on the HttpGet call, where I set the SelectListItems

Comment: Create a private method in your controller (say) `private void ConfigureViewModel(SellingAdViewModel model)` that populates all the selects and call this in the GET method and POST method before you return the view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you this solution put your model in a `TempData` during your GET action And if the model state is invalid you make an assignment like this

```
public ActionResult CreateSelling(SellingAdViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        SellingAdvert sellingAdvert = setSellingAd(model);

        var stored_advert = sellingAdvertService.Create(sellingAdvert);



        if (User != null && User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            if (model.AcceptPartner)
            {
                notifyPartner(stored_advert);
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Upgrade", "Ads", new { AdvertID = stored_advert.Id });
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("ActivateAnonymous", "Ads", new { AdvertID = stored_advert.Id, anonymousId = model.UserId, AdvertType = "selling" });
        }
    }

    model.YourList = TempData.Peek("YourList");
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: This is not a good solution. If the user refreshes the page then `TempData` will be null and an exception will be thrown. As for the suggested link, its got nothing to do with this (unless OP wants to render hidden inputs for each `SelectListItem` property of each `SelectList` which would be plain stupid)

Comment: That's not true, if the user refresh the page the GET action will reassign the TempData...

Comment: No that's not correct. The initial GET adds the values to `TempData`. When the form is submitted, the values are loaded correctly from `TempData` and returns the view. If the user now refreshes the form, it goes to the POST method (not the GET method) and since `TempData` only survives one request, the value is now null and an exception is thrown. I suggest you give it a try.

Comment: Eventually he can try to TempData.Keep() the values

Comment: Yes, that's one option. `.Peek()` is probably sufficient. [Peek vs Keep](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21252888/tempdata-keep-vs-peek). I suggest you edit answer.