# mvc-pass data from controller to view of other controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewbag, viewdata

I am having a `AccountController` in which I have an action `YNHHConsentForm` inside this action I am redirecting to another View using `RedirectToAction("Index", "Default")`. Now I want to show a message on Index page of Default. I have tried to pass value using `ViewBag` or `ViewData` but it remains `null` and I am unable to use its value on Index.

AccountController

```
   public ActionResult YNHHConsentForm(YNHHFormVM model)
    {
        if (result == 0 || isSuccess == false)
        {
            model.FormSubmissionMessage = "Something went wrong please try again";
            return View(model);
        }
        else
        {
            SessionItems.IsAuthorizationFormFilled = true;
            //ViewBag.FormSubmissionMessage="Form submitted successfully";
            ViewData["FormSubmissionMessage"] = "Form submitted successfully";
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Default");
        }
    }
```

Index(Default)

```
   @if (ViewData["FormSubmissionMessage"] !=null)
            {
                <div class="alert alert-success">
                    ViewData["FormSubmissionMessage"].ToString()
                </div>
            }
```

I am using `ViewBag` and `ViewData` for first time so not able to figure out where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `TempData`. In the `YNHHConsentForm()` method

```
TempData["FormSubmissionMessage"] = "Form submitted successfully";
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Default");
```

and access it in the `Index()` method (and add it to (say) `ViewBag` so you can then access it in the view.

```
ViewBag.MyMessage = TempData["FormSubmissionMessage"];
```

and in the view

```
<div class="alert alert-success">@ViewBag.MyMessage</div>
```

For an explanation of the difference between `ViewData` `ViewBag` and `TempData`, refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993263/viewbag-viewdata-and-tempdata)

Side note: `TempData` only lasts one redirect so if the user refreshed the browser, the message would not be generated again. You can use `.Keep()` or `.Peek()` to solve this if its critical (refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21252888/tempdata-keep-vs-peek) for more detail)

Answer (score 2):

To complement @StephenMueke's answer, I typically create a pair of components for the scenario it seems you're using (displaying system acknowledgements). It consists of:

1. A static class containing the status/alert types as strings.
2. A partial view that gets rendered on the layout, so that the message is in a consistent location.

The static class looks something like this:

```
public class Alert
{
    public static string Error = "alert-error alert-danger";
    public static string Info = "alert-info";
    public static string Warning = "alert-warning";
    public static string Success = "alert-success";

    public static string[] All = new string[]{ Error, Info, Warning, Success };
}
```

Essentially, these are the Bootstrap alert classes, but they're generic enough to work without Bootstrap. The `Alert.Error` value contains two "classes" to make it compatible with both version 2 and version 3 of Bootstrap.

The partial view checks `TempData` for the `Alert` values, and if found generates a Bootstrap alert:

```
@foreach (string key in Alert.All)
{
    if (TempData.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        <div class="alert @key">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-times"></i></button>
            @Html.Raw(TempData[key])
        </div>
    }
}
```

I use `Html.Raw` so that I can include markup in the message, if I want to emphasize part of the message:

```
TempData.Add(Alert.Success, "<b>Thank you!</b> Form submitted successfully!");
```

would be rendered as:

> **Thank you!** Form submitted successfully!