# Tempdata peek function not returning value after postback

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

I am learning MVC and testing the keep and peek methods of `Tempdata`. `Keep()` method returning me the value of `tempdata` across `postback` but `peek()` method not returning value across `postback`. 
Also, I set the value to `tempdata` and in view, I didn't read that value but still across `postback` it didn't persist. I have used exact code used in the tutorial. It's working over there but not working in my machine. Is there any issue with VS because only `peek()` method is not working.
Heres my controller code:

```
public class TempDataController : Controller
{
    // GET: TempData
    public ActionResult ShowTempData()
    {
        TempData["Test"] = "Showing Value Of TempData";
        return View();
    }
}
```

And heres my view code:

```
 <div>
    @{ 
        string str = TempData.Peek("Test").ToString();
    }

    @str;

</div>
```

I don't see issue with this code. Can you please tell me?

Comment: Just clarify "its working over there but not working in my machine" => are you want to say that the `Peek()` method **only** not working in dev environment?

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21254178/6311571) That will help you to understand Peek along with Keep

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Thanks for your reply and sorry for my bad english. I am watching online video tutorials and doing practice. What i mean is the teacher of video tutorials uses same above code and its working properly on his machine but its not working on my machine.

Comment: @ZiaulKabirFahad thanks for your reply. The link is very helpful. What i am saying is i havent read the value of tempdata in above code. So if i refresh my page then inside my controller i should get value of TempData["Test"]. But i am getting null value for the same.