# How to return model to view that requires ViewData in .net core MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, viewbag

I have .net core mvc application, which has two action methods inside post controller.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create()
{
  var hostAppGetQuery = new Application.Handlers.HostApps.Queries.List.Query();
  var platformGetQuery = new Application.Handlers.Platforms.Queries.List.Query();

  var hostApps = await _mediator.Send(hostAppGetQuery);
  var platforms = await _mediator.Send(platformGetQuery);

  ViewBag.hostApps = ((Application.Handlers.HostApps.Queries.List.Response) hostApps).Items;
  ViewBag.platforms = ((Application.Handlers.Platforms.Queries.List.Response) platforms).Items;

  return View();
}
```

above is get method which have two `ViewBag` Variables.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Models.InputModels.Posts.Create.Index model)
{
   if (!ModelState.IsValid)
   {
     return View(model);
   }

   var command = _mapper.Map<Application.Handlers.Posts.Commands.Create.Command>(model);

   var result = await _mediator.Send(command);

    return View();
}
```

above is post method to create post.
i'm getting error here because not returning the viewbag variables in post action.
But i'm little bit confused here. do i need to get and set viewbag variables every time post method is called ?? 
Is there any method to persist this data , without calling database every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ViewData` or `TempData`  to persist your variables from one `Controller` action to another. You would use `ViewBag` when you want to return a value to your `View`. If you want to persist your TempData values for more requests you can use Peek and Keep functions. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21252888/tempdata-keep-vs-peek) can give more insight on these functions. In your case, you can do something like:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create()
{
  var hostAppGetQuery = new Application.Handlers.HostApps.Queries.List.Query();
  var platformGetQuery = new Application.Handlers.Platforms.Queries.List.Query();

  var hostApps = await _mediator.Send(hostAppGetQuery);
  var platforms = await _mediator.Send(platformGetQuery);

  TempData["hostApps"] = ((Application.Handlers.HostApps.Queries.List.Response) hostApps).Items;
  TempData["platforms"] = ((Application.Handlers.Platforms.Queries.List.Response) platforms).Items;

  return View();
}
```

And your `post` method would look like:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Models.InputModels.Posts.Create.Index model)
{
   if (!ModelState.IsValid)
   {
     return View(model);
   }

   var command = _mapper.Map<Application.Handlers.Posts.Commands.Create.Command>(model);

   var result = await _mediator.Send(command);

   //Get your ViewData variables here
   if (TempData["hostApps"] != null)
   {
    var hostAppsResult = (((Application.Handlers.HostApps.Queries.List.Response) hostApps).Items) TempData["hostApps"];
        ...
   }

   //Get your ViewData variables here
   if (TempData["platforms"] != null)
   {
    var platformsResult = (((Application.Handlers.Platforms.Queries.List.Response) platforms).Items) TempData["platforms"];
        ...
   }

    return View();
}
```

You can read more about this topic in this [article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-use-viewdata-viewbag-and-tempdata-in-mvc/)